# How can I change an object without refreshing the file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I run this inside a function, and click either one of the touchableOpacity I have to save the code for it to check the id number then return the correct outcome

```js
const pressHandler = (id) => {
    if (id == 1) {
      Pressedinfo = <View>
        <Text>one</Text>
      </View>
    } else if (id = 2) {
      Pressedinfo = <View>
        <Text>two</Text>
      </View>
    }
  }
  in the return (view):
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler(1)}>
 
          <Text style={Styles.Text1}>1</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler(2)}>
          <Text style={Styles.Text1}>2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {Pressedinfo}
```

Comment: You have to use state so it can re-render component.

Comment: How do I use a state inside a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `state`.   Move your react element out of the function and just manipulate the string in state.

In your constructor create a state:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {textString: ''}
}

const pressHandler = (id) => {
    if (id === 1) {
      this.setState({textString : 'one'})
    }
    else if(id === 2) {
      this.setState({textString : 'two'})
    }
  }
```

For the  template:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler(1)}>

       
      <Text style={Styles.Text1}>1</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler(2)}>
      <Text style={Styles.Text1}>2</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <View>
    <Text>{this.state.textString}</Text>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would try.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [Pressedinfo, setPressedInfo] = useState(null)
  const pressHandler = (id) => {
    if (id == 1) {
      setPressedInfo(<View><Text>one</Text></View>)
    } else if (id = 2) {
      setPressedInfo(<View><Text>two</Text></View>)
    }
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler(1)}>
        <Text style={Styles.Text1}>1</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler(2)}>
        <Text style={Styles.Text1}>2</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {Pressedinfo}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this.state method to change the components without re rendering the page.